# Is there something like a private FAQ/ask-the-expert?

Tags: 7

I've been looking for a module that allows something like *ask the expert* with these conditions:

- A registered user `U` uses a form to submit the question. Anonymous users do not have access to this section.
- The expert `E` is notified of the new question by email.
- When `E` answers the question, `U` is notified by email.
- `U` can only see the questions asked by himself/herself (with their respective answers). No regular user can see the questions asked by other user, or the answers given to other users.
- An administrator `A` can see all the questions and answers at all times.

The modules [faq](http://drupal.org/project/faq) and [faq_ask](http://drupal.org/project/faq_ask) seem like an option, but I can't use the traditional FAQ format, since that format allows all users to see all questions. The module [question](http://drupal.org/project/question) is not available for Drupal 7.

Is there anything like what I'm describing? If not, is there any way of modifying, for example, the `faq` module, so permissions will work the way I want?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The [question_answer](http://drupal.org/project/question_answer) module is probably what you want. I used to make a private Q/A for registered users on a site. All the "workflow" you talk about can be done via either the workflow module, drupal actions or the [Maestro](http://drupal.org/project/maestro) module ... I'd give Maestro a shot only because I haven't used it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try what you say, though it might take a while, since I haven't used any of those modules before.

Comment: just food for thought. You could make a taxonomy for "expertise" and use something like the Relation module to build a relation of User <- is an expert -> Expertise so you have a list/pool of people to get emails (or to make a drop-down of people to select as your Experts to whom a question should go to). Relation is more of an API than an easy to use UI based module, where for instance Maestro is pretty damn user friendly for your use-case I think ...